# Is stratis service suppose to create /stratis for device files?

Tags: linux, rhel, partition

According to redhat documentation on - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_file_systems/managing-layered-local-storage-with-stratis_managing-file-systems

Example 23.1. Viewing the UUID of Stratis file system
`lsblk --output=UUID /stratis/my-pool/fs1`

When I created a stratis filesystem there is no directory called /stratis. When I execute `stratis filesystem list` the device is under `/dev/stratis/pool1/stratis-filesystem1`.
I checked couple of textbooks on RHCSA and the examples they show the path under `/stratis/pool/fileystem`

Even when trying to mount, the device used to mount is `/stratis/mypool/filesystem` whereas I have to use `/dev/startis/mypool/filesystem` I am not sure where the discrepancy is coming from. I am using RHEL 8.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is outdated (at least partially), the directory used for stratis devices was changed from `/stratis` to `/dev/stratis` in 2.2.0 ([release notes](https://stratis-storage.github.io/stratis-release-notes-2-2-0/)). 8.4 has stratis 2.3.0 so just use `/dev/stratis`.

Comment: I see. I am not sure what version of RHEL8 I would be tested on and these differences might screw me up.

Comment: Red Hat says the RHCSA exam is based on 8.2 [here](https://www.redhat.com/en/services/training/ex200-red-hat-certified-system-administrator-rhcsa-exam) (but I'm not sure how accurate or up-to-date the information is) [which means stratis 2.0.0](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/8.2_release_notes/rhel-8-2-0-release#technology-preview_file-systems-and-storage) and the "old" `/stratis` directory